# Zendesk Server side app: Securing the app

Tags: zendesk, zendesk-app

I'm going through the article at https://developer.zendesk.com/documentation/apps/build-an-app/building-a-server-side-app/part-5-secure-the-app/ to try to implement authentication for a server-side app. It works great for my subdomain. However, when I try to install it on another account (with a different subdomain), there is an error when attempting to open the JWT token.

Additionally, I would like to ask how I can obtain the installation ID of the app, which is used to open the JWT token. This ID should be unique for each installation.

Answer (score 1):

To obtain the installation ID, you can utilize the following endpoint: https://your-subdomain.zendesk.com/api/v2/apps/installations.json

It's crucial for your app's security to have the installation ID. You can refer to the following link for more information on obtaining your app's ID:
[Getting Your Zendesk App's Public Key and Installation ID.](https://developer.zendesk.com/documentation/apps/build-an-app/building-a-server-side-app/part-5-secure-the-app/#getting-your-zendesk-apps-public-key-and-installation-id)